# How can I efficiently pack binary data into a file in Python?

Tags: python, file-io, binary

I would like to write binary data to a file in Python without sending it through temporary buffers first. How can I use the `struct` module directly on a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I was able to pack binary data directly into a file under Python 3. The only drawback is that you need to guess a maximum size for the file before writing the data. (An additional call to `truncate` can be made at the end if the guess is too big.)

Two things are going on here. The file is being memory mapped, and `struct` is being used to pack data into a `memoryview` of that memory map. By using a `memoryview`, it is possible to use the Python buffer interface to write directly to the file. `struct`'s `pack_into` function can write into anything that supports the buffer interface. This technique can also be used by using a `memoryview` on a socket to write binary data directly to a socket.

```
import struct
import mmap

with open('test.bin', 'wb') as f:
    f.truncate(100)

with open('test.bin', 'r+b') as f:
    m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
    mv = memoryview(m)
    for ind in range(25):
        struct.pack_into('>l', mv, ind * 4, ind)
```

Also, note that it's probably better to make fewer calls to `pack_into`, and calling it in a loop here is just for illustrative purposes.